# Slim template: use Pandoc as markdown converter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, pandoc, slim-lang

I use [slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim) as template syntax in a Rails project. I always loved its `markdown:` feature.

For the current project I have to export some markdown content to different formats, e.g. PDF. I use [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) for this, which has enhanced capabilities for markdown.

Now I wonder whether I can tell slim to use pandoc as default markdown converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement own Pandoc [template engine](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/blob/master/lib/tilt/kramdown.rb) and [register](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/blob/master/lib/tilt.rb#L109) it in `tilt`. `slim` will use your template engine automatical (for any case check that you don't user other Markdown engines such as karmdown, etc.)

Comment: I've created a pull request on the repository. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction. https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/pull/276